# unexpectedly found nil when use userDefaults

Tags: ios, swift

I add @IBAction for button:

```
  @IBAction func addThemeAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        var userDefaults:NSUserDefaults=NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        var itemList:NSMutableArray!=userDefaults.objectForKey("itemList") as NSMutableArray}
```

When I press button I get fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no object for the key `itemList` in your `NSUserDefaults`. Instead of force unwrapping it with `!`, check if optional is `nil` and conditionally unwrap it:

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

var itemList = userDefaults.objectForKey("itemList") as? [AnyObject]

if let itemList = itemList {
    // itemList is not nil, use it here
} else {
    // itemList has never been set, perhaps use some default
}
```

Also, `userDefaults` doesn't need to be a `var`.

You can change `[AnyObject]` to something else if you know the type (like `[String]`, for example).

Answer (score 0):

One: You can never guarantee that some key is present in your user defaults, so this is a crash waiting to happen. Two: I don't think dictionaries that you read from user defaults are mutable.